# How to overlay two 39200x30288 images in app

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to overlay two 39200x30288 images by Python. I was trying to do that like that:

```
from PIL import Image

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

image_1 = Image.open(r"1.png")
image_2 = Image.open(r"2.png")

image_1 = image_1.paste(image_2, (0,0))

print(image_1.size)
```

And have this type result error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Projects\plus\app.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(image_1.size)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Have someone solve this kind of problem?

Comment: 39200x30288 is 1.19 **giga**pixels, two of those means over two gigapixels. that'll take RAM on the order of 2-8 gigabytes -- https://xyproblem.info/ explain what you're **really** up to

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
image_1 = image_1.paste(image_2, (0,0))
```

It doesn't return a new image, because it already knows where to paste `image2` - it pastes it onto `image1`. So it returns `None` and that is why you get the error message that `None has no size`.

You simply need:

```
image_1.paste(image_2, (0,0))
```